# Pinch gesture on iPad Air 2 messes with Touch ID

Tags: ios, ipad, gesture, pinch, touch-id

My app supports Touch ID login for users. When a user opens the app the Touch ID dialog is shown and asks for user action.
When running on the iPad Air 2 the user can do a five-finger-pinch and move the app to background. The problem is that the Touch ID dialog is still shown.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?